# How to implement Google Text to Speech in Electron?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, electron

I'm using the official module @google-cloud/text-to-speech into Electron.
My setup is:

- Electron 4.0.0
- Node 10.11.0

I followed all the instructions of this [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/text-to-speech) but I'm continuing to have an error that I cannot fix.

```
Uncaught (in promise) NodeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.basename (path.js:749:5)
    at GrpcClient.loadProto (C:\ELECTRON\new2\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:119:29)
    at new TextToSpeechClient (C:\ELECTRON\new2\node_modules\@google-cloud\text-to-speech\build\src\v1\text_to_speech_client.js:106:38)
    at quickStart (file:///C:/ELECTRON/new2/index.html:38:20)
    at file:///C:/ELECTRON/new2/index.html:58:3
```

In index.html:38:20 there is the function

```
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
```

that return this error.

There is another big question: **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**.

Into Electron, how I have to set it? I want to include the json (downloaded from Google) in distributable version of the app. At this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) I only found how to set the variable on the backend Windows/Linux.

Comment: post your codes here,  `C:/ELECTRON/new2/index.html:58:3`

Comment: The code I'm using is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/text-to-speech).
index.html:58:3 is **quickStart();**

Comment: Have you created cloud project?

Comment: TextToSpeechClient() function requires the project information as parameter

Comment: 1. Register project first here. https://console.cloud.google.com/project

Comment: 2. Enable billing at your project. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project?visit_id=637226505363321398-1562752023&rd=1#enable-billing

Comment: 3. Enable speech API here. https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=texttospeech.googleapis.com

Comment: 4. Finally https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** file, this variable should be set in the windows/linux/MacOs environment.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable

> Setting the environment variable allows you to provide credentials
>   separately from your application, without making changes to
>   application code when you deploy.

After checking and testing the Text to Speech [code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/text-to-speech) you shared, I was able to execute the example (without Electron), the error you are getting seems related to how you are handling the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I did it these steps but it doesn't work.

In reality there is another strange thing: I had to change the source code.
There was this line `source = util.fs.readFileSync(filename).toString("utf8");` that gave me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of null
at fetch (C:\ELECTRON\new2\node_modules\protobufjs\src\root.js:160)`

Change it in `source = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString("utf8");` it start to give me the error reported in my frist post.

As I told, I have followed the steps. I have the json stored in the electron folder
`

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "XXXXXXX",
  "client_id": "XXXXXXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXXXXXX.gserviceaccount.com"
}`
```

I think that my error is to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, that I have to implement in Electron and I don't understand yet how to setup it

Comment: Remove this answer and add this to your question. :) once you register you will get that credentials and export it to the node env

Comment: You are right. But the question characters allowed is shorter respect to the content. (too long by 587 characters)